# Using any in re.findall - Python

Tags: python, regex, list, variables, numbers

I wrote a script in python to tell which numbers in new were in the first 10 numbers in new. I know it looks more complicated than it has too and that has to do with what I'm trying to do with the script later. For now though I'm trying to figure out why it's printing 'each' for EVERY number in the list 'new' and not just the ones before the tenth.

Here's my code:

```
i = 10
new = ['A lot of numbers'] 

for each in re.findall(r'[0-9]+', new):
    if any(each for x in (re.findall(r'[0-9]+', new)[0:i])):
        print each
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: This throws TypeError because new is a list.  What version of python are you using?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do, possibly including a real example of the `num` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to x somehow in your generator expression, or else you're just checking `any([each, each, each, ....])`, which will always evaluate to true if each evaluates to true (which it always will for your regular expression).  I suspect you want something like this, which tests if any of the first i items is equal to each:

`if any(x==each for x in (re.findall(r'[0-9]+', new)[0:i])):`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the first 10 letters in `new`, did you mean

```
if any(each for x in (re.findall(r'[0-9]+', new[0:i]))):
```

rather than:

```
if any(each for x in (re.findall(r'[0-9]+', new)[0:i])):
```

Also, did you mean for `new` to be a list? A list can't be passed to `findall`.

Finally, note that you never need an `else: pass` statement, an `if` works fine on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If new is a list of strings, some of which are numbers like "123", and you want the first 10 of these numbers:

```
allnumbers = [x for x in new if re.match("[0-9]+", x)]
first10numbers = allnumbers[:10]
```

(For Python 2.x)

If new is a string, you'd have

```
allnumbers = [x for x in re.findall("[0-9]+", x)]
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing with this later, but if you're just trying to print the later numbers only if they show up in the first 10 numbers, you might just go like:

```
for number in [x for x in allnumbers if x in first10numbers]:
    print number
```

Comment: I guess you mean print number instead of print x on the last line